# How same data type behaves when do + operation

Tags: go

Just started learning Go on packthub. In one of the quizzes, I saw this question and ran it on my VScode. I want to know why I am getting this answer. Here is the code.

```
package main
   import "fmt" 

   func main() {
        a := uint8(255)
        b := uint8(127)
        c := a + b
        fmt.Println(a, "+", b, "=", c)
   }
```

The output is 126. How please?

Comment: Please remove the java tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to understand uint8. Uint8 has a range from 0 to 255, not more than that. You have declared "a" and "b" as uint8. You are declaring "c" with implicit type which makes it uint8, which has the maximum value of 255. That is why your output is 126. (not 127 because "0" is also counted)

To make this work just change the type of "a" and "b"

```
package main
import "fmt" 

func main() {
   a := uint16(255)
   b := uint16(127)
   c := a + b
   fmt.Println(a, "+", b, "=", c)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes a whole lot of sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You declared both variables as uint8 which means it takes max 8 bit in memory and that's only a positive value so maximum number could be 2^8 (256).

Now when you add two numbers it simply adds it and returns the output => 255 + 127 = 382;

But variable c is also uint8 type and this number goes out its range so to fit this number in the variable it subtracts output with max number and adjusts in the variable C.

```
a + b = 255 + 127 = 382

c = 382 - 256
  = 126
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer, as it explains what go does to keep the value within type boundaries, and how it arrived at 126.